# Some Bootstrap 5 icons are not showing up

Tags: html, icons, bootstrap-5

I am having issues with bootstrap 5 not showing certain icons. The bi-search shows perfect, but bi-send does not appear at all. I would normally put this in a code snippet, but the feature does not look to be available anymore so bear with me as I post the html that replicates this issue:

```
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- CSS only -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
      <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
<body>
                    <!-- This code shows the search icon fine, but send and many others do not work-->
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-send"></i><i class="bi bi-search"></i></span>
                    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your Bootstrap Icons import is for an older version, `send` icon didn't exist in that one.

Use the latest version 1.8.1 (as of 26th March 2022):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">`

**Version 1.10.5 Update (as of 10th May 2023):**

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">`

You can always find the latest version [here](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#install).

Comment: I swear I checked that. Thanks!

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
This is current as of 13th Nov 2022

Comment: I don't know where I got version 1.5.0 from when I've just started using it in March 2023... Anyway, updating it to 1.10.3 worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to add bootstrap-icons.min.css to

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
```

2. Then, you can use this two ways seamlessly ( download bootstrap icons to your project and use it in two )

1. `<i class="bi bi-facebook"></i>`
2. `<img alt="Bootstrap" src="bootstrap-icons-1.10.5/graph-up.svg">`

good work to you

Answer (score 0):

You can add following -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use the icons with NextJS and have the same problem. They don't display. That is why I use the SVG for the icons and it works every time.